# Is there a Lebesgue integrable function $f$ such that the set of points on no neighborhood of which $f$ is bounded has positive Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I tried to prove that there are none using the definition of the Lebesgue integral of nonnegative functions (by converting it into an improper Riemann integral of another variable, see Wikipedia for that) but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Do you mean: "Is there a Lebesgue-integrable function such that the set on which it is infinity has positive measure?"? - In which case the answer would be no.

Comment: I cannot make grammatical sense of this. Please try a re-write. Try not to put everything into one sentence.

Comment: A precise formulation: does there exist $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ and a set E of positive Lebesgue measure such that  for any x in E and any neighborhood  V of x the essential supremum of f is $\infty$?.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Let $$g(t)=t^{-1/2}\chi_{(0,1)}(t),$$ say $(t_n)$ is a countable dense subset of $\Bbb R$, and define $$f(t)=\sum2^{-n}g(t-t_n).$$

Then $f$ is integrable but $f$ is unbounded in *every* nonempty open set.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as a point where a function is unbounded.   For every $n$,, $f$ is unbounded in every neighborhood of $t_n$. If $V$ is a nonempty open set there exists $n$ with $t_n\in V$,  hence $f$ is unbounded  in $V$.

Comment: But how does one prove the integrability of that function? Dominated convergence?

Comment: @JustAYoungArtist Monotone convergence.